# Erro na conexão com banco de dados oracle depois que faz publish no azure com visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-azure, oracle12c

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em asp.net com Oracle data base 12c. A conexão com o banco de dados, localmente, funciona. Faz todas as funções CRUD. Também estou utilizando os serviços da azure (exigência do projeto), tanto para o banco quanto para o site.
Quando faço publish com o Visual Studio e o site é publicado, pela azure também, não é possível estabelecer uma conexão com o banco de dados. 
Todas as dll oracle estão no projeto. Mas somente quando sobe para o serviço de publicação da azure, não é possível conectar com o banco.

Exemplo da connectionstring funcionando localhost.

```
<connectionStrings><add name="Ativos" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=IP/DATA;PASSWORD=SENHA;USER ID=USUARIO;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings></configuration>
```

Alguém já teve algum problema semelhante?

Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Seu web.config esta com a connectionstring correta?

Comment: Olá, está sim. Até que no localhost a conexão com banco externo funciona. Consigo inserir na máquina virtual da azure com o banco, somente quando eu faço a publicação que não conecta.
Coloquei o exemplo dela na pergunta.

Comment: Consegue se conectar com alguma ferramenta de management?